# In App Purchases without registered accounts

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Is it possible to create an app without the user registering but able to subscribe to in app purchases with ability to cancel?

Is this possible with Android/iOS?

Comment: on iOS yes, because the subscription is linked to their App store account and cancellation is through Apple's interface.  It is suggested that you also have your own account system to make it easier for the user to consume their subscription on multiple devices, but you can also provide a "restore purchases" button to let them access their purchase.